# sqls processed inside a begin end block in sybase ase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a stored procedure with a begin end block. For example there are few select statements and update statements in that block.

Inside this begin block, are all the sqls executed together or sequentially according to how they are written?

```
    begin
      select stmt
      update stmt
      select stmt
      .
      .
    end
```

Comment: Are you asking wethet the statements are executed sequentially or in parallel, or what exactly is the question? :)

Comment: Yes. I want to know if all the sqls are executed one by one in the order in which it is defined or all the sqls in the begin end block parallel.basic idea is i have a dead lock and we want to know if its because of the begin end block

Comment: The deadlock should not be because of severeal statements executed in one procedure by one thread. But if the procedure is executed simultaneously by many threads, it could dead lock.

Answer (score 1):

The statements in a stored procedure are executed sequentially.

The only thing you do not know the ordet of, and that can be executed in parallel, are the different substeps internally in each statement.

For example, in:

```
    SELECT a, b
    FROM table t
    INNER JOIN other o
       ON o.id = t.id
    INNER JOIN third d
       ON d.o_id = o.o_id
    WHERE t.b = 123

    UPDATE t
    SET x = 123
    FROM table t
    WHERE t.b = 234
```

The select will always be executed before the update, but in the select statement, you do not know if 'table' is joined with 'other' first, and the joined with 'third', or if 'other' is joined with 'third' and then with 'table'.

Answer (score 0):

All statements in begin - End block executed sequentially .
I have faced this issue of deadlock and its possible because procedure must be running in multiple thread.

If this can be executed in single or 2-3 threads and transactions are small then process can wait before it get escalated to deadlocks. or else add try catch block with error number for deadlock to retry update if its deadlock error.